# Getting an index based on name and number of files in a directory. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have a user place json files into a directory. I then want a way to be able to grab the name, put it into a list, and instantiate it through a prefab so that it can be viewed and so that the file can be loaded. I would imagine some sort of delegate would work, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to make. du you want a list of filenames displayed on the screen which than can be loaded?

Comment: yes b, that's about what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in the namespace `System.IO` you'll find the static `Directory`, `File` and `Path` classes.

The `Directory` class has a method called `GetFiles()` which returns a string array of all the files in the given directory. You can use a searchpattern like "*.json" to only get json files. By using `Path.GetFileName()` or `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` you can get the filename for display.
By using `File.ReadAllText()` you can read the entire file as a single string and with `File.ReadAllLines()` you can get every line separated in an array.

In Unity you'll probably want to have a user interface which you populate with elements representing these files.

I'd suggest that the templates you use for instancing in this list, contains a small script without any `Update` methods that simply holds the value for the filename (with directory) and maybe its contents. You can add methods that load that file on click.

It really depends on what you want to do with it. There is no delegate needed, since you only have to call the method which is available.

Comment: Thanks Max! I'll give it a go. Would this work on Android also?

Comment: Depends on the location of the files, but I would say: yes.